# What solves my problem: Map, reduce or a recursion?

Tags: r, recursion, purrr

I really need some help to write a recursion in R.

The function that I want changes a certain observation according to a set of comparisons between different rows in a data frame, which I shall call `g`. One of these comparisons depends on the previous value of this same observation.

Suppose first that I want to update the value of column `index`, row `i` in my data `df` in the following way:

```
    j <- 1:4
    g <- (df$dom[i] > 0 &
          abs(df$V2009[i] - df$V2009[j]) <= w) |
          df$index[i] == df$index[j] 

    df$index[i] <- ifelse(any(g), which(g)[[1]], df$index[[i]])
```

The thing is, the object `w` is actually a list:

```
w = list(0, 1, 2, df$age[i])
```

So, as you can see, I want to create a function `foo()` that updates `df$index` iteratively. It changes it by looping through `w` and comparisons depend on updated values.

Here is some data:

```
df <- data.frame(dom = c(0, 0, 6, 6), 
                 V2009 = c(9, 11, 9, 11), 
                 index = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
                 age = c(2, 2, 2, 2))
```

I am not sure if a recursive function is actually needed or if something like `reduce` or `map` would do it.

Thank you!

Comment: Number of rows in `df` and length of `w` would always be the same? Can you show your expected output?

Comment: I'm away from the computer right now, but w would always have length 4. The number of rows in df might change - the idea would be to wrap this around a function also, so that the user could change df as well.

Comment: I don't understand how you define `j`, is the value `4` the number of rows of df, the value of `i`, the length of `i`, a fixed number?

Comment: I'm sorry, by trying to simplify, I ended up confusing things a bit. Yes,  j would be the number of rows of df. As for i, it would actually vary in the sense that I would like to apply this procedure to all rows in df

Comment: `(df$dom[i] > 0 & abs(df$V2009[i] - df$V2009[j]) <= w &)` why a `&` at the end? Is it by mistake?

Comment: Why is `w` a list? It could be a vector as well.

Comment: Yes! Sorry, I will edit it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an attempt of my own. I guess I figured out a way to use recursion over `mutate`:

```
test <- function(i, df, k){
  j <- 1:nrow(df)
  w <- list(0, 1, 2, df$age[i])
  g <- (df$dom[i] > 0 & abs(df$V2009[i] - df$V2009[j]) <= w[k]) |
    df$index[i] == df$index[j]          
  l <- ifelse(any(g), which(g)[1], df$index[i])
  return(l)
}
    
loop <- function(data,
                 k = 1) {
  data <- data %>%
    mutate(index = map_dbl(seq(n()),
                           ~ test(.x, df = cur_data(), k)))
  if (k == 4) {
    return(data)
  } else {
    return(loop(data, k + 1))
  }
}

df %>% loop()
```

I welcome any comments in case this is inefficient considering large datasets

Answer (score 1):

The following function uses a double `for` loop to change the values of column `index` according to the condition defining `g`. It accepts a data.frame as input and returns the updated data.frame.

```
foo <- function(x){
  change_index <- function(x, i, w){
    j <- seq_len(nrow(x))
    (x$dom[i] > 0 & abs(x$V2009[i] - x$V2009[j]) <= w) |
      x$index[i] == x$index[j]
  }
  for(i in seq_len(nrow(x))){
    W <- list(0, 1, 2, x$age[i])
    for(w in W){
      g <- change_index(x, i, w)
      if(any(g)) x$index[i] <- which(g)[1]
    }
  }
  x
}

foo(df)
#  dom V2009 index age
#1   0     9     1   2
#2   0    11     2   2
#3   6     9     1   2
#4   6    11     1   2
```

Comment: thank you! This seems to work, I'll just tweak it a little bit by replacing the loops by map as much as possible

Comment: @ArthurCarvalhoBrito I didn't use map because it more naturally gets a copy of `df$index`, then, for each `i`, changes `df$index[i]` (the copy) and returns it to caller. The result is a matrix of vectors each with one element updated. The `for` loop gets the original vector and updates it. When done it's still one vector only, not as many updated copies as `nrow(df)`.

Answer (score 0):

One can define `w` inside a function and use lexical scoping (closure).
Using your instructions, the function `index_value` calculates for any given `i` the index value.

`correct_index_col` returns the corrected `df`.

```
df <- data.frame(dom = c(0, 0, 6, 6), 
                 V2009 = c(9, 11, 9, 11), 
                 index = c(1, 2, 1, 2),
                 age = c(2, 2, 2, 2))


index_value <- function(df, i) {
  j <- nrow(df)
  w <- c(0, 1, 2, df$age[i])
  g <- (df$dom[i] > 0 & abs(df$V2009[i] - df$V2009[j]) <= w) |
        df$index[i] == df$index[j]
  ifelse(any(g), which(g)[[1]], df$index[[i]])
}

correct_index_col <- function(df) {
  indexes <- Vectorize(function(i) {
    index_value(df, i)
  })
  df$index <- indexes(1:nrow(df))
  df
}

# > correct_index_col(df)
#   dom V2009 index age
# 1   0     9     1   2
# 2   0    11     1   2
# 3   6     9     3   2
# 4   6    11     1   2
#
```

If you want to really update (mutate) your `df`, then you have to do
`df <- correct_index_col(df)`.